# Why doesn't the ray which is refracted take the other path which makes the same angle with the normal?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

[image]

So this is the classical picture of refraction. My question is why doesn't the refracted ray take the other path which also has the same angle with the normal like in the second image?[image]

Comment: 1. Why do you think it would? Have you ever seen it do that in the real world? 2. What's your educational background? Do you know how to solve boundary value problems for EM plane waves?

Comment: Why would it? Is there anything special about this alternative ray path that you drew, or are you simply asking why light refracts the way it does?

Comment: *I think it would because the condition i am talking about also obeys snell's law. @SamuelWeir

Comment: @ThePhoton I am a highschool student but don't hold back any explanation. explain it at the highest level you understand it.

Comment: @Черенки - No, Snell's Law says that the light refracts the way shown on the original diagram. The ray that you drew is in the opposite direction to the normal of the interface, so your ray has an angle with the same absolute value as the angle given by Snell's Law, but with the opposite sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component of momentum parallel to the surface must be conserved.  The parallel component of the "backwards" ray is the negative of the "forward" wave.

In other words, the "backwards" ray does not conserve momentum.